# Assign First Element of Nested Array as Property of Parent Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Assuming the following Array:

```
[
{id: 1234, name: "@Acme", sources:["Twitter"]},
{id: 5678, name: "@Enron", sources:["Facebook"]},
]
```

I want to promote `sources[0]` to a property value, either under sources itself or as a new key using `lodash`.

I've done the following:

```
myList = _.map(monitorList, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['id', 'name', 'sources']));
mySources = _.map(monitorList, 'sources');
```

I imagine I can iterate through each respective array now and map my index from `mySources` to the sources key in `myList`, however it seems like there should be a functional way using lodash to promote a nested array item to a property value.

Ideal final data structure:

```
[
{id: 1234, name: "@Acme", sources:"Twitter"},
{id: 5678, name: "@Enron", sources:"Facebook"},
]
```

Comment: Could you also show the intended output structure you want to achieve?

Comment: @guwere updated with more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow a simple path and use `forEach` to replace `sources` property:

```js
var items = [{id: 1234, name: "@Acme", sources:["Twitter"]},
             {id: 5678, name: "@Enron", sources:["Facebook"]}];

items.forEach((item) => item.sources = item.sources[0]);

console.log(items);
```

Another solution, using `map`, which is more functional (as it does not change `items` variable):

```js
var items = [{id: 1234, name: "@Acme", sources:["Twitter"]},
             {id: 5678, name: "@Enron", sources:["Facebook"]}];

var newItems = items.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item, { sources: item.sources[0] }));

console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: Note that doing it this way mutates the original array.  That could be ok but its not very functional.

Comment: @terpinmd. That's true. Edite my answer to include a more functional solution. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted an answer in `lodash`, but it's pretty similar and I didn't care about mutation of the original array in this case, so your solution put me on the right path: 

`_.forEach(monitorList, monitor => monitor.sources = monitor.sources[0]);`

Comment: Yeah, _.forEach ends up being equivalent to Array.prototype.forEach

Comment: @TylerMills, I'm a bit confused how to reconcile *"there should be a functional way"* with *"I didn't care about mutation"*.

Comment: @trincot I was addressing more functional than comparing two arrays by looping over the indices, however you're right that `map` is truly functional.

Comment: I gave the answer in lodash

Answer (score 2):

With a functional ES6 approach:

```js
const monitorList = [
    {id: 1234, name: "@Acme", sources:["Twitter"]},
    {id: 5678, name: "@Enron", sources:["Facebook"]},
];

var result = monitorList.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { sources: o.sources[0] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use map:

```
var array = [{id: 1234, name: "@Acme", sources:["Twitter"]},
              {id: 5678, name: "@Enron", sources:["Facebook"]}];


var items = array.map(item => {
  item.source = item.sources[0]; 
  return item;
});
```

You could change item.source to item.sources as well if you wanted to overwrite.

Another way using some losdash methods:

```
var items = array.map(item => {
  return _.assign({}, item, {sources: _.first(item.sources)});
});
```